# SpringBoot disable Actuator root

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openshift, prometheus

I'm using Spring Boot and exposing metrics with actuator and prometheus. I want to expose `info`, `health`, `metrics`, `prometheus`, `shutdown`, and nothing more. But even if I specify into the application properties, what I see is that even the root `/actuator` is exposed.

I would like to disable the root actuator and have only the 5 members I said previously.

Is there a way to don't expose only the `/actuator` endpoint? I've also tried in application properties doing like this:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude=actuator
```

That is the list of the exposed actuator:

```
{
   "_links":{
      "self":{
         "href":"http://localhost:9002/actuator",
         "templated":false
      },
      "health-component-instance":{
         "href":"http://localhost:9002/actuator/health/{component}/{instance}",
         "templated":true
      },
      "health-component":{
         "href":"http://localhost:9002/actuator/health/{component}",
         "templated":true
      },
      "health":{
         "href":"http://localhost:9002/actuator/health",
         "templated":false
      },
      "shutdown":{
         "href":"http://localhost:9002/actuator/shutdown",
         "templated":false
      },
      "info":{
         "href":"http://localhost:9002/actuator/info",
         "templated":false
      },
      "prometheus":{
         "href":"http://localhost:9002/actuator/prometheus",
         "templated":false
      },
      "metrics-requiredMetricName":{
         "href":"http://localhost:9002/actuator/metrics/{requiredMetricName}",
         "templated":true
      },
      "metrics":{
         "href":"http://localhost:9002/actuator/metrics",
         "templated":false
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: No there isn't as `/actuator` is the main entry point for all other actuators.

Answer (score 6):

There is no configuration value for this. The best you can do right now is move the management base endpoint to `/`, in which case the discovery page is disabled to prevent clashing with other endpoints in your app:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-hypermedia

> When the management context path is set to /, the discovery page is disabled to prevent the possibility of a clash with other mappings.

If you're using Spring Security you can effectively hide the discovery page using something like this inside your own `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
   http
      .authorizeRequests()
         .mvcMatchers("/actuator").denyAll()
         .mvcMatchers("/actuator/").denyAll()
}
```

This would deny all requests to the discovery page, but allow requests through to the individual exposed endpoints.

There is some discussion of the discovery page in this GitHub issue as well:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10331

Comment: Hi mike, thanks for replying.
i didn't understand how to override the actuator path. i tried exposing an api rest at the same path, but mine is not considered

Comment: Good, like this actuator is not expose.
but now isn't there a way to expose the actuator under /actuator instead of the main root?

Comment: Correct, that's the downside I was pointing out: all the exposed endpoints are now under `/` instead of `/actuator`.

Comment: I have added a spring security code sample for how to hide the discovery page while leaving the exposed endpoints working.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.4/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.endpoints.hypermedia):

> To disable the “discovery page”, add the following property to your
> application properties:
>
> ```
> management.endpoints.web.discovery.enabled=false
> ```